# Trying to upgrade phpMyAdmin in MAMP

Tags: phpmyadmin, upgrade, mamp

I'm trying to upgrade phpMyAdmin on my installation of MAMP. Everybody points to [this page](http://blog-en.mamp.info/2013/08/how-to-upgrade-phpmyadmin-in-mamp-mamp.html) for instructions, but I get stuck at step 3 because I don't have a /Library/Application Support/appsolute folder from which to copy the config.inc.php file.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking in your /Username/Library/Application Support/appsolute folder. Ensure you are looking in your Mac's base directory, ie. in your Finder window click on Macintosh HD to locate your base Library.

The link you share with the instructions works perfectly for me.